# Java socket connection Reuse

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a java socket code where I have to send multiple messages without losing connection, connection will be ended when I stop the script.

I am not able to proceed with it, can anyone assist with any approach we can use to achieve this objective.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please supply some code so we can see what you have accomplished so far?

Comment: 'Not able to proceed' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a single thread server client message communication,
you can simply use a while loop to keep communicating rather than ending it.

If there is code for checking/improving will be a great help.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of a long-lived server:

```
ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9090);
try
{
    while (true)
    {
        Socket socket = listener.accept();
        System.out.println("Got a new connect from a client");
        try
        {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println("hello from the server");
        }
        finally
        {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    listener.close();
}
```

Comment: Here is an irrelevant example of a long-lived server that doesn't send or receive multiple messages, which is what the question is about.